# XML C# Parse - Complex

Tags: c#, xml

I have been on google for a while but am just stumped.  I need to parse xml of this nature.  I can't seem to skip to elements in the middle, e.g. Folder.  I have limited the xml as there were many 'Folder' elements.  Any guidance would be appreciated.  I was after the FolderID element's attribute ID.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="14" 
        MinorVersion="1" 
        MajorBuildNumber="225" 
        MinorBuildNumber="46" 
        Version="Exchange2010_SP1" 
        xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <m:GetFolderResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" 
        xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <m:ResponseMessages>
        <m:GetFolderResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
          <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
          <m:Folders>
            <t:Folder>
              <t:FolderId Id="AAMkADk5MmY1ZThmLTM2MzAtNGVh" ChangeKey="AQAAABYAAACSe/NBrSZiQKqHx8yL+lIRAAAA1EWM" />
              <t:ParentFolderId Id="AAMkADk5MmY1ZThmLTM2MzAtNGVh" ChangeKey="AQAAAA==" />
              <t:DisplayName>Top of Information Store</t:DisplayName>
              <t:TotalCount>0</t:TotalCount>
              <t:ChildFolderCount>15</t:ChildFolderCount>
              <t:EffectiveRights>
                <t:CreateAssociated>true</t:CreateAssociated>
                <t:CreateContents>true</t:CreateContents>
                <t:CreateHierarchy>true</t:CreateHierarchy>
                <t:Delete>true</t:Delete>
                <t:Modify>true</t:Modify>
                <t:Read>true</t:Read>
                <t:ViewPrivateItems>true</t:ViewPrivateItems>
              </t:EffectiveRights>
              <t:PermissionSet>
                <t:Permissions>
                  <t:Permission>
                    <t:UserId>
                      <t:DistinguishedUser>Default</t:DistinguishedUser>
                    </t:UserId>
                    <t:CanCreateItems>false</t:CanCreateItems>
                    <t:CanCreateSubFolders>false</t:CanCreateSubFolders>
                    <t:IsFolderOwner>false</t:IsFolderOwner>
                    <t:IsFolderVisible>false</t:IsFolderVisible>
                    <t:IsFolderContact>false</t:IsFolderContact>
                    <t:EditItems>None</t:EditItems>
                    <t:DeleteItems>None</t:DeleteItems>
                    <t:ReadItems>None</t:ReadItems>
                    <t:PermissionLevel>None</t:PermissionLevel>
                  </t:Permission>
                  <t:Permission>
                    <t:UserId>
                      <t:DistinguishedUser>Anonymous</t:DistinguishedUser>
                    </t:UserId>
                    <t:CanCreateItems>false</t:CanCreateItems>
                    <t:CanCreateSubFolders>false</t:CanCreateSubFolders>
                    <t:IsFolderOwner>false</t:IsFolderOwner>
                    <t:IsFolderVisible>false</t:IsFolderVisible>
                    <t:IsFolderContact>false</t:IsFolderContact>
                    <t:EditItems>None</t:EditItems>
                    <t:DeleteItems>None</t:DeleteItems>
                    <t:ReadItems>None</t:ReadItems>
                    <t:PermissionLevel>None</t:PermissionLevel>
                  </t:Permission>
                </t:Permissions>
              </t:PermissionSet>
              <t:UnreadCount>0</t:UnreadCount>
            </t:Folder>
          </m:Folders>
        </m:GetFolderResponseMessage>
      </m:ResponseMessages>
    </m:GetFolderResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: What does "I can't seem to skip to elements in the middle" mean? Does it mean you have some code? If so, show it.

Comment: Is this a namespace issue? Do you know how to read namespaces?

Comment: Perhaps you should read [ask]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ to XML is the best .NET XML Parsing API.
See
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/xdocument-class-overview

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp12
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\foo.xml");
            var ns = (XNamespace)"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types";

            var folders = doc.Descendants(ns + "Folder");

            foreach (var e in folders)
            {
                var folderId = e.Element(ns + "FolderId").Attribute("Id").Value;
                Console.WriteLine(folderId);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about serlialization.  It's very easy to convert an XML to and from a object in C#.  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483055/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part

That said, this will get you the data you're after. It's not very reusable and won't help you with any xml files other than ones with one instance of that attribute, but it's what you're after so here you go.

```
string FolderId;
string ChangeKey;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:\\myfile.xml"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains("<t:FolderId Id="))
        {
            try
            {
                var lineArray = line.Split('\"');
                FolderId = lineArray[1];
                ChangeKey = lineArray[3];
            }
            catch
            {
                // handle exception
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [XSD.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe) to create a schema class. and then using XML deserializer, you can deserialize/parse xml to object

Answer (score -1):

Using xml linq

```
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<XElement> folders = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Folder").ToList();
            XNamespace tNs = folders.FirstOrDefault().GetNamespaceOfPrefix("t");
            XElement id_AAMkADk5MmY1ZThmLTM2MzAtNGVh = folders.Where(x => (string)x.Element(tNs + "FolderId").Attribute("Id") == "AAMkADk5MmY1ZThmLTM2MzAtNGVh").FirstOrDefault();
```